# Apache Camel Custom Exit Error

Tags: json, apache-camel, output, processor

I have the following Apache camel to make a post to a URL.

```
        .setHeader(HTTP_PATH,simple("/product-catalog/insert"))
        .setHeader(HTTP_METHOD,constant("POST"))
        .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
        .setBody(constant(""))
        .process(new ProductProcessor())
        .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .to("{{products.endpoint}}?bridgeEndpoint=true")
        .unmarshal().string()
        .setHeader("CamelJacksonUnmarshalType", constant(ProductInsertResponse.class.getName()))
        .unmarshal(ProductResponse)
        .process(new ProductResponseProcessor())
```

After this call, on the processor I would like to check if the product code for this new product is correct, as follow:

```
public class ProductResponseProcessor implements Processor 
{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        ProductInsertResponse response = (ProductInsertResponse) exchange.getIn().getBody();

        if(response.productCode().equals("0")){
            // The product code is not correct
            // And I would like to return a JSON to the browser with the following format
            // {"response":"Error","errorString":"Error insert product" ,"errorCode":"0"}
        }
    }
}
```

if the code is not 0 I would like to continue with my other task in the apache camel flow. I don't know how to cut the route on this point and send a JSON object to the browser in case of our product code is equal to 0.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have number of different options.

simple ones:

- throw exception from your processor and then catch it in the route in `onException` or surround your processor with camel `doTry`
- set special Exchange property in the processor then analyze it in the route and fork your flow as you need.
  ...

Comment: Thanks! you give me the clue.
I included this instruction in the processor:

exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);